# :state breaking when using multiple returns?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm still learning Vue, and JavaScript.  I've had an input box setup for awhile now to check that numbers are being entered and put the red rectangle around the box if not.  Here's that code.

```
<b-form-input v-model='itemNum' type="text" :state="itemNoState" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'
/>
```

Then in computed

```
itemNoState() {
   return !isNaN(parseFloat(this.itemNum)) && isFinite(this.itemNum) ? null : false;     
}
```

Now, I also want to check if the number they are typing has already been added to the item object.  That is here:

Method:

```
item(itemNumber) {
  return this.$store.getters["build/item/item"](
    this.buildNumber,
    itemNumber
  );
}
```

Store:

```
  item (state) {
    return (buildNumber, itemNumber) => {
      const b = Util.parseInt(buildNumber)
      const i = Util.parseInt(itemNumber)
      return _get(state, b, i)
    }
  }

const _get = (state, buildNumber, itemNumber) => {
  const items = _all(state, buildNumber)
  if (items.hasOwnProperty(itemNumber)) {
    return items[itemNumber]
  }
  return null
}
```

Now I've tried adding to the itemNoState something like

```
return this.item(this.itemNum) ? null : false;
```

But it just breaks everything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please define it just breaks everything.

Comment: Also, I see you're using `$store` so are you using `vuex`? If so, you should take a look at the manual on getters / actions etc as you're using it a little out of line with best practices which is only going to help in confusing things.